# Speed of comparison vs copying in array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, performance, sorting

I've been comparing selection and insertion sort. As much as I know insertion sort works on inversion count rather depends on it. But in the worst case the total inversion count will be maximum and in insertion sort, the no of swaps will be maximum/greater than selection sort, as in selection sort totals swaps are always order of input size 'n' and not more than that and it will be much lesser than in insertion sort.

In the worst case, time complexity will depend on the number of comparisons(which are equal or less in case of selection sort) and number of swaps(which are more in insertion sort).
So, if swapping/writing is faster I can use insertion sort but if writing is costly compared to comparison then I will use selection sort.
So, which sorting algorithm will be better in the worst case and how will it be decided that speed of comparison is greater or speed of copying is greater if I'm using an array as a data structure.

Comment: If you're asking about time complexity in big O notation, then the speed of copying/comparison is a constant so should be ignored, and you get that they're both equally complex (`O(n^2)`). If you're asking about "practical" efficiency, in terms of runtime speed on a real computer, then you'll need to profile it on the computer you're wanting to run these algorithms on.

Comment: let's say i'm using same computer to sort them both then which will be faster insertion or selection? in worst case for same input?

Comment: It depends on the computer you're running them both on, the language you use, the optimizations you enable in the compiler, how well you write your code, etc. That's why you have to do actual profiling as @hnefatl suggested.

Comment: @TusharBhaskar Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 0):

Number of **comparisons** in the worst case is same for both *insertion sort* and *selection sort* which is **O(nxn)**. However key thing to note is:

*Number of comparisons in selection sort is always **O(nxn)*** while:

*Number of comparisons in insertion sort is **O(n)** in best case.* The best case is when data is already sorted.

So, if the *number of comparisons* is the criteria for measuring performance, **Go For Insertion Sort.**

However one should also note:

*Number of swaps in selection sort is **O(n)** for worst case.* while:

*Number of swaps in insertion sort can go up to **O(nxn)** for worst case.*

So, if the *number of swaps* is the criteria for measuring performance, **Go For Selection Sort.**